# Vue js axios post request to golang server, Preflight error

Tags: javascript, go, axios, preflight

I try to send a post api request from a front end website (localhost:8888) to a golang backend (localhost:8000). I get the errors listed below. I looked on stackoverflow and the problems seems to be cross origin request and preflight request handling. I added the headers as shown below but the problem still occurs. I hope you guys can help me :)

Axios error:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:8000/api/heimdall/signup 404 (Not Found)

Failed to load http://localhost:8000/api/heimdall/signup: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8888' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

Mux CORS handler

```
methodsOk := handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "HEAD", "POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS"})
originsOk := handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"*"})
headersOk := handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"Accept", "Content-Type", "Content-Length", "Accept-Encoding", "X-CSRF-Token", "Authorization"})

log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", handlers.CORS(methodsOk, originsOk, headersOk)(r)))
```

Axois Code:

```
'use strict';

 var axios = require('axios');

function Signup(email, password) {
var apiURL = 'http://localhost:8000/api/heimdall/signup';

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios.post(apiURL, {
        email: email,
        password: password
    })
    .then(respone => {
        console.log('Promise Signup response:', respone);
        resolve(respone);
    }, error => {
        console.log('Promise Signup error:', error);
        reject(error);
    });
});
}

export {
   Signup
};
```

Comment: Can you try to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in your allowed headers? and see if it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try this, i use this on my web api.

```
var handler http.Handler
{
    handler = handlers.CORS(
        handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"*"}),
        handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "PUT", "PATCH", "POST", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"}),
        handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"Origin", "Authorization", "Content-Type"}),
        handlers.ExposedHeaders([]string{""}),
        handlers.MaxAge(10),
        handlers.AllowCredentials(),
    )(r)
    handler = handlers.RecoveryHandler(handlers.PrintRecoveryStack(true))(handler)
}
http.Handle("/", handler)
http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this type of problem in laravel 5.5 (PHP)

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Cache-Control, Pragma, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Encoding");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
```

you can try this type headers on golang

Comment: I tried both your suggestions, but it does not work. Preflight is still unsuccessful.